# Tools for automating UI testing for web

Tags: automated-testing, selenium-webdriver, selenium-ide, web, uiautomation

Recently I got a task to find a tool that can be used to test web UI. I found Selenium IDE and also used to it. But the problem is that I have to test on Chrome and IE as well. I tried Selenium WebDriver - it works but needs long time to code. Can you guys suggest me any other tool like Selenium IDE or any plugin I can use to test?

If I am doing anything wrong kindly guide me as well.

Comment: WebDriver "takes long time to code", but your code is more flexible (can do stuff which IDE never could), less brittle (better deals with page changes), and after you developed base, you can add new functionality faster and in more flexible way. Of course you need to be decent programmer to be able to use incredible benefits of WebDriver - that's why it is becoming W3C standard.

Answer (score 2):

Could you please specific your kind of test? You want to do regression testing or ... If selenium web-driver is taken a long time, I think you should consider to :

- 1- iMacro:
  https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/imacros-for-firefox/?src=hp-dl-upandcoming
- 2- Sauce labs: https://saucelabs.com/

But before you get approach to automation, please discuss with your team or your upper manager about:

```
1 - Project Scope
2 - Budget
3 - Human Resources
4 - AUT characteristics
5 - Your working process
```

Those metrics will likely affect:

```
1. If the project should have automation or not.
2. If yes, which tool to support. 
3. When have tool, which resource to prepare. 
4. When have tool and team, how to adjust the working process to best optimize the automation
```

To be honest, automation(web-driver) takes time and effort to fully see its value, so take your time :-).

Answer (score 1):

You can use

1. BadBoy
2. WatiR or WatiN (it has WaitN test recorder and supports IE 6, 7, 8 & 9 and Firefox 2.x & 3.x)

tools too for testing Web UI.

But, are you looking for free tools only? 
There are number of paid tools which provide multiple browser support and very easy to use and implement. But again you have to discuss this thing first within your project, even if your client is not willing to pay for this, you can still share the cost within multiple projects (if that's possible in your organization).

From your side as a proactive action, you can create a **DAR (Decision Analysis Report)** for both Free and Paid tools considering the below mentioned parameters and thus share your report with the management and show your findings. Whichever tool you choose you need to learn it a bit and then you can use it.

1. Platforms, Technology and Types supported
2. Features provided and required
3. Manual and Automatic Test creation
4. Change Management/Maintenance of Test cases
5. Results Management and Reporting
6. Data In, Data Out
7. Training required and Tester skillset
8. Integration with the Test and task management tool (you would like that failed test cases should get reported automatically to your bug tracker)
9. Ease of use
10. Online support, discussion forums and service

Answer (score 1):

Telerik test studio - licensed 
iMacro
[Applitool](https://applitools.com/sign-up/) - UI based automation (pxl to pxl verification, layout, content etc)

Let me know if you need a help on above things.

Answer (score 1):

I can recommend Ranorex. It works both with coding and without (just by capturing the actions). It also supports cross-browser web test automation (Chrome, Firefox, IE and Safari) as you can read [here](http://www.ranorex.com/web-test-automation.html).

Answer (score 1):

You can use Katalon Studio, it provides both record & playback feature along with scripting capabilities.
It has a gentle learning curve with a pre-configured framework and support for cross-browser testing and what you are trying to achieve can be done in a couple of days only. You can learn about it here - [Katalon Studio Tutorial](https://artoftesting.com/katalon-studio-tutorial)

Answer (score 1):

Selenium is the technology which the browser manufacturers have agreed to support.  So Selenium itself is not usually the choice.  (the only exception are UI 'diff' tools which are generally in their infancy).

So really the choice is:

- You do the programming
- You use a vendor who provides an interface on top of selenium that you find easier to use.  See the many examples cited by others.

The problem I found with UI 'diff' tools is that they seem to be going the opposite way to general trends.  What I mean is that they are not usually aimed at the code developers themselves.  This leads to the age old problem we are trying to solve, i.e. devs and qa are separated and testing is seen as checking, the relationship is combative rather than complimentary and not as providing immediate feedback to the actual developers writing code in the current context.

Answer (score 0):

If your company has some cash, buy Telerik Test Studio. It will do IE, Firefox, Chrome, and soon mobile. It is way easier than Selenium. The only drawback is no OSX, which means no Safari. I use a Mac as my main machine so I manual test on that and then automate.

Answer (score 0):

There are many tools available the best one is **katalon** if you don't want to write long code, you can just **record the script and play it** as well as you can code if you want to.
here is some reference link where you can find many other options also.

```
https://www.softwaretestinghelp.com/best-gui-testing-tools/

https://www.guru99.com/top-20-web-testing-tools.html
```

Answer (score 0):

As illustrated in [All You Need To Know About UI Testing](https://www.lambdatest.com/blog/all-you-need-to-know-about-ui-testing/), Selenium is the best way to go for automated UI testing. A great learning curve helps you run the Selenium tests quickly and easily. To have hassle-free testing, you can use an online cross-browser testing platform that integrates with Selenium and can provide many features through drag and drop functionality.

There are a few good tools available online as well:

[LambdaTest](https://www.lambdatest.com/): Offers a cross-browser testing cloud, to help you test your website across 2000+ real browsers for both desktop & mobile. You can even automate browser testing using its [online Selenium Grid](https://www.lambdatest.com/selenium-automation) and have a [developer-friendly browser](https://www.lambdatest.com/lt-browser) that is designed to fasten your responsive testing.

[Grunt](https://gruntjs.com/): Grunt is a Javascript-based selenium automation GUI & UI testing tool. It provides a lot of plugins for the easy performance of the tasks.

[Karma](https://karma-runner.github.io/latest/index.html): Karma is a Javascript runner tool that helps in GUI & UI testing. It can also be used to run the Jasmine tests. Karma comes loaded with helpful tools and features for test running.

[Katalon Studio](https://www.katalon.com/): Selenium requires extensive coding knowledge and testing expertise. To shorten that learning curve, you can try Katalon Studio for codeless automation. Katalon allows teams at any level to transform into automation testing quickly and easily.